# How do you use grails to connect to wcf HTTPS endpoint w/ Username authentication?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, grails

I'm running a WCF service in IIS7 with Username authentication and Message Security.

A client wants but develops using GRAILS. How do they go about connecting and authenticating with the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails does not handle web services as part of the core framework. Grails is written in Groovy which allows you to use any Java library out there. I would recommend using one of the JAX-WS implementations of web services for Java. Either CXF or Metro should do what you need.

Essentially you just want to build a client and then call it from the grails application.

- CXF - http://cxf.apache.org/
- Metro - https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/